# how to text align a typography element of mui whose parent's position is fixed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

**Home Component**

```
const Home = ({ mode, setMode }) => {
  return (
    <Box m={-1} sx={{overflowX:'hidden'}}>
      <Navber/>
      <Stack direction="row" spacing={2} justifyContent="space-between">
        <Leftbar/>
        <Feed/>
        <Rightbar/>      
      </Stack>
    </Box>
  );
};
```

**Leftbar**

```
const Leftbar = () => {
    const styles = {
      typo: { 
        position: 'fixed',
        color:'blue',
        textAlign: 'center', 
      },
    };
return (
      <Box
        flex={3}
        p={2}
        bgcolor="red"
        sx={{ display: { xs: 'none', sm: 'block' } }}
      >
        <Box position="fixed" maxWidth="20%">
          <Typography   variant={'h4'} style={styles.typo}>
          Sam Aggarwal
          </Typography>
        </Box>
      </Box>
    );
  };

  export default Leftbar;
```

I've tried everything, including relative positioning and inline blocks, but I still can't get the element to be in the centre. Specifically, I want the first typography element to be in the centre, and the remaining typography elements to be under the first one on the left.
Don't move the second box, though, since I require that position to be corrected.

Please Provide Assistance!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can add `width: "100%"` to your `typo` style like this:

```
typo: {
  position: "fixed",
  color: "blue",
  textAlign: "center",
  width: "100%"
}
```

You can take a look at [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-jasper-syfjwv?file=/src/App.js) for a live working example of center aligned `Typography`.

Comment: Nah , it got in the center of full display (middle of the yellow part)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you have to use position `fixed` for the parent! The box with position `fixed` and `wdith: 20%` will only give this typo to move to at most `20%` of screen.

Honestly your left red box doesn't seem to be just `20%`. It looks like `30%`. So it won't center if you use position `fixed` with wrong `width`!

But to be center of the `fixed` parent use this:

```
typo: {
  position: "relative",
  color: "blue",
  textAlign: "center",
  width: "100%"
}
```

Comment: Nah , it still in the left